# Impossible to send SIGKILL to supervisord

Tags: python, docker, process, supervisord

[Supervisord](http://supervisord.org/index.html) is run in a docker container. It spawns several processes. Its configuration is below:

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon = true

[group:maria-as]
programs=p1,p2

[program:p1]
priority = 1
command = bash ./launcher.sh
stopasgroup=true
killasgroup=true
autorestart=false

[program:p2]
priority = 1
command = bash ./launcher2.sh
stopasgroup=true
killasgroup=true
autorestart=false

[eventlistener:subprocess_stop]
events=PROCESS_STATE_EXITED,PROCESS_STATE_FATAL,PROCESS_STATE_STOPPED,PROCESS_STATE_BACKOFF
command=/kill.py
```

My goal is to kill supervisord with all its subprocesses once one of the subprocesses goes down. So event listener was implemented which sends SIGKILL to supervisord.

*kill.py* code is below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import signal

def write_stdout(s):
   sys.stdout.write(s)
   sys.stdout.flush()
def write_stderr(s):
   sys.stderr.write(s)
   sys.stderr.flush()

def main():
   while 1:
       write_stdout('READY\n')
       try: 
            print time.time()
            os.kill(1, signal.SIGKILL)
            print time.time()
       except Exception as e:
               write_stderr('Could not kill supervisor: ' + e.strerror + '\n')
       write_stdout('RESULT 2\nOK')
if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

But nothing happens once one of the subprocesses goes down.

What is more interesting is that running *kill -9 1* inside the container has no effect either.

*kill -9 -1* causes the container to go down, but it takes several seconds.

How to send SIGKILL to supervisord so that the container would stop immediately and what's the reason for such a behavior?

Comment: Only the process that runs as pid1 will receive the SIGKIL so make sure that supervisor is pid 1.
`docker exec` into your container and do a `ps aux |grep supervisord` to see the assigned pid.

Use `exec` if needed to force supervisord to be pid1.
Eg: `COMMAND: initscript.sh && exec supervisord ...`

Comment: supervisord has pid 1 and still not possible to send sigkil to supervisor